# how to do a vertical-align:bottom but up 10px

Tags: css

I'd like to have two inline-blocks with the second being vertical-align:bottom but up 10 pixels. I'm not sure how I would do this. I am thinking something like this but how do I move  test2 class up 10 pixels?

```css
.test1{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.test2{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='test1'>
    here is some info
  </div>
  <div class='test2'>
    here is more info
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is the answer: just add `margin-bottom: 10px`

```css
.test1{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.test2{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='test1'>
    here is some info
  </div>
  <div class='test2'>
    here is more info
</div>
</div>
```